# Eloquent query AND OR

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a scenario in which I'm searching through a database using Eloquent in Laravel.

I have the following query:

```
$search = $request->get('q');

$users = User::where('username', 'like', '%' . $request->get('q') . '%')
            ->orWhere('displayName', 'like', '%' . $request->get('q') . '%')
            ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%' . $request->get('q') . '%')
            ->orWhere('role', 'like', '%' . $request->get('q') . '%')
            ->orWhere('department', 'like', '%' . $request->get('q') . '%')
            ->orWhere('location', 'like', '%' . $request->get('q') . '%')
            ->orWhere('directDialIn', 'like', '%' . $request->get('q') . '%')
            ->orWhere('mobileNumber', 'like', '%' . $request->get('q') . '%')->get();
```

and I have the following query scope:

```
/**
 * Scope a query by published
 */
public function scopePublished($query)
{
    return $query->where('published', 'open');
}
```

I want to use the query scope to only search open articles.

I know you can chain `where` like this: `Article::where()->where()->where()->get()`

I get a bit confused with the chaining but I want to say: search the article columns with a LIKE operator but only where an article is open.

Without sounding dense, is there an easy mindset to convert my RAW SQL thought into Eloquent queries?

In my head, it would be a base query looking for open articles and then a nested query that searches through each field.

Comment: `User::where...->published()->get()` might work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a nested `where()` constraint:

```
User::where(function($query) use($request) {
    $query->where('username', 'like', '%' . $request->get('q') . '%')
        ->orWhere('displayName', 'like', '%' . $request->get('q') . '%')
        [...]
})->published()->get();
```

Comment: Just so I don't trip over in the documentation, this is similar to a WHERE IN in bog standard MySQL? So the where is a query itself, before applying further constraints?

Comment: No, it's just the equivalent to using brackets: `... WHERE (username LIKE '%...%' OR displayName LIKE '%...%' ...) AND published = 'open'`

Comment: Oh... so it isn't even as complex as I thought? I think I just confused myself. Is there a way to log the SQL created via Elequent in Laravel?

Comment: Replace `->get()` with `->toSql()`.

Comment: Or wrap the query in `\DB::enableQueryLog(); dd(\DB::getQueryLog());`.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database